# How to create snowflake security admin role and at same time restrict the permission only on one database

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Environment: snowflake database.
i am trying to find a way to create a role which have security admin permission but should limit the permission only to specific database. is this doable or not? if so, anyone can help me on this? thanks so much.

Thanks, Alex

Comment: Hi - which of the privileges that SECURITYADMIN has that are relevant to databases, do you want this new role to have?

Answer (score 0):

SECURITYADMIN is a role created by default in Snowflake and a lot of his permissions are not database-related (for example role and user management). Indeed most of the database-related grants belongs to SYSADMIN role.

So if you want to create a custom role having limited permissions on a specific database. You should list the permission which are database related and grant this permissions to the custom role.

For example if you want to give all privileges to a role on a specific database you can use :

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE my_db TO ROLE my_custom_role;
```

Answer (score 0):

Roles are account-level, not db-level objects. So I am guessing you are trying actually to do the same role mgmt that SECURITYADMIN does, but at db-level. In that case:

```
use role SECURITYADMIN;
create role SECURITYADMIN_DB1;
grant create user, create role to SECURITYADMIN_DB1;
```

After that create Access Roles for your db:
https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/security-access-control-considerations.html#aligning-object-access-with-business-functions

Then assign all access roles to the custom SECURITYADMIN_DB1 role, so your role will manage that particular db only.